# Roots of $p$-adic irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

A finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ posesses the property that for any irreducible polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ adjoining *any* root of $f$ automatically adjoins *all* roots of $f$. (In other words, any extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is normal.)

Does the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ posess the same property? If no, is it true for irreducible polynomials $f\in\mathbb{Q}_p[x]$ with coefficients in the set $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$?

Comment: Adjoining a root to the field, I guess.

Comment: @Zardo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The question is whether a finite extension $L$ of our given field $K$ is normal, or not. If it is normal, then every irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ that has one root in $L$, has all of its roots in $L$.

Finite extensions of finite fields are Galois, hence normal. Finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, however, need not be normal in general. However, if the extension $L/K$ is unramified then $L/K$ is Galois (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156490/unramified-p-adic-extension-implies-galois)).

Comment: I'll think it over a bit. I've edited the question putting some restriction on coefficients of the polynomial (so that they belong to $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$). Your post seems to be relevant in this case too. Do polynomials with such simple coefficients generate only unramified extensions?

Comment: @YauhenRadyna: The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ (the usual Eisenstein), has all its coefficients in your set, but gives rise to a ramified extension. It's still obviously normal. Need to think of another example to get that.